# Add cshtml page in classic asp website. a link on classic asp page, when click, it must open the cshtml page

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp-classic

i have a already running website build on classic asp. Now i want to add a single cshtml page in this website and want to open it on the click of a link. The link is in inside classic asp page.

How can i keep single cshtml file inside classic asp website and make it working?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read up on how to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)  You may also benefit from [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What is expected of SO users](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: You can't keep cshtml file inside classic asp website because these bother are based on different architectures

Comment: But I need to do it anyway. Is there really no way?

Comment: You've tagged with at asp.net-mvc. Do you actually want MVC or just 
 a cshtml (Razor) page?

Comment: @Jacob M.   I just actually want a cshtml(Razor) page inside a classic asp (vbscript based) website and try to post form data from classip asp page to cshtml page.

Comment: @IkramShah You can have a classic asp page and a razor cshtml page in the same website, and for that matter a webform aspx file and a php file.  All that matters is that you have all the relevant technologies installed and enabled on your server.

Comment: @Sachin.  This question might be helpful, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29823833/how-to-call-cshtml-file-directly-with-cshtml-extension-from-browser-without-us

Answer (score 0):

Updated from @John's comment - this is possible, but note that I had to start from a .NET site and copy the ASP Classic files into it instead of starting with an ASP Classic site.

Then in web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

Then its just a simple:

```
<a href="classicPage.asp">Go to classic page</a>
```

Comment: They might use different technologies, but that doesn't mean you cant have them in the same website.  It's true that the two types of pages wouldn't be able to share the same session object

Comment: @John I wasn't able to get this to work, can you? I was able to mingle .aspx and .asp pages in the same document root, but not .cshtml and .asp. I'm still tinkering as I'd like a solution to this as well, so I'd be grateful if you have one.

Comment: For me it was a simple case of adding `<add key="webpages:Enabled" value="true" />` to the web config file.  See the link I posted in my last comment on the original question.

Comment: Thank you! You should post it as an answer so others who stumble over this can see it more easily! Right now they'll just see me nay-saying lol.